# How can i reverse slice of list in Python? At each step we invert an interval of the list and output the entire list

Tags: python, slice, reverse

At each step we invert an interval of the list and output the entire list.

input:

```
3: number of member of list
1 2 3 :list's members
3 :number of indexes of list
2 3: index
2 2: index
2 3: index
```

output:

```
1 3 2
1 3 2
1 2 3
```

Code:

```
n=int(input())
a = [i for i in map(int,input().split())]
q=int(input())
for i in range(1,q+1):
    l=[i for i in map(int,input().split())]
    a[::-1]
    print(a)
```

Comment: And what's your question? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you might want to do something like this,

```
mem = int(input("Number of members: "))
members = [int(i) for i in input("List members: ").split()]
idx = int(input("Number of indexes: "))
indexes = [tuple(map(int, input("index: ").split())) for i in range(idx)]

for a, b in indexes:
    members[a - 1], members[b - 1] = members[b - 1], members[a - 1]
    print(members)
```

Input:

```
Number of members: 3
List members: 1 2 3
Number of indexes: 3
index: 2 3
index: 2 2
index: 2 3
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 2]
[1, 3, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

from what I understand from the title :

> How can i reverse slice of list in Python? At each step we invert an
>   interval of the list and output the entire list

you want to reverse a subsequence from a list, here is an example of how you can do it:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
start, stop = 1, 4

my_list[start: stop] = my_list[start: stop][::-1]

print(my_list)
```

output:

```
[1, 4, 3, 2, 5]
```